# Android animation Frame dropped a lot when view Layout at same time

Tags: android, android-animation, frame-rate

I have a 500ms animation.The animation dropped like 10 frame during the running time.
After cheack Trace file. I found out the problem is caused by some view doing their onLayout method.
Like some view is showing after net-data comeback, but before that fragment already shown and do it's transforming animatioin. When net-data come back with transforming animation not finished, I have to show them on screen and caused new rendering. Then the problem caused.

Only I can do is delay net-data shown after all animation finished?
And why system default transform don't meet this problem?

How can I solve this problem except delay.
Anyone can give some Info about this? Very appriciate it.

Comment: Could you provide your code, stacktrace and your sample video, so we can understand it  better? May be thread handling may cause this issue, but we can't say anything without seeing your code. Please provide your code. You should provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.